# Vb.net Property use another property

Tags: vb.net, oop, properties

Here is my program:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Class Component
        Public Shared Methane, Ethane As New Component

        Public Shared ComponentList As New List(Of Component)(New Component( {Methane, Ethane})
        Public Property Mole As Double
        Public Shared MoleSum = ComponentList.Sum(Function(item) item.Mole)
        Public Property NMole As Double = Mole/Molesum
    End Class

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Component.Methane.Mole)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Component.Ethane.Mole)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(Component.Methane.NMole)
    End Sub
End Class
```

So the questions are:

1. Is that correct to use property in another property like I did? If it is not, how can I do the same functionality?
2. Variable `Molesum` does not work if it is mentioned inside of `Component` class. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Please define "correct to use". One definition would be that if it compiles, it's correct. That code compiles if you replace `New Component( {Methane, Ethane}` with `New Component() {Methane, Ethane}` and explicitly define `MoleSum` `As Double`. Whether it all means and does what you want is a different question.

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will point out some problems for you.

Comment: Do you intend for `NMole` to be the *current* value of `Mole/Molesum` any time it is retrieved? Or do you only intend for it to be initialized to the initial value of `Mole/Molesum`, and then update it manually?  I believe it will do the latter as coded.  Similarly, did you intend for `Molesum` to be a function, or for it be a field with an initial value of `ComponentList.Sum...`?  Again, I believe it will be the latter as coded.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. So basically I would like to implement the following: I will have a lot of variables like Methane, Ethane, Propane, Butane etc. All of them have some molar mass, corrected molar mass etc. So, I want to be able to do some calculation with one filed (or more) for all variables. For example, I need to calculate Sum of Molar mass (Molesum) of all variables (Some of .Mole) and then for all variables do the following: .Nmole= .Mole/Molesum. I thought it would be quite smart to do it in property to avoid excessive typing for every variable

Comment: Correct - I mean in terms of coding, because I am just starting with vb.net and coding at all and I suppose my idea and implementation may be wrong and inefficient. So, any of your comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: So an the problem is that when I am calling 'Component.ComponentList.Sum(Function(item) item.Mole)' - it works perfectly outside of the class, but I would like to do all these staff inside of my Component class, so, after just after pushing the button will be able to display 'MsgBox(Component.Methane.Nmole.Tostring)'. Right now it is just displaying 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who has the same problem, solution below:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Class Component
        Public Shared Methane, Ethane As New Component

        Public Shared ComponentList As New List(Of Component)(New Component( {Methane, Ethane})
        Public Property Mole As Double
                Public Shared Function MoleSum() As Double
            Return Component.ComponentList.Sum(Function(item) item.Mole)
        End Function
                Public ReadOnly Property Nmole As Double
            Get
                Return MoleSum()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Component.Methane.Mole)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Component.Ethane.Mole)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(Component.Methane.NMole)
    End Sub
End Class
```